# Не подключаются scripts в WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем привет!

Много, кому задавал вопрос, но по ответам мне не помогло разобраться с проблемой. В общем, натягиваю кастомную тему на WordPress, подключаю рабочие скрипты (100% проверено), они не подключаются. Консоль их просто не видит, ошибок не выдает.

wp_head(); wp_footer(); оба подключены, где надо.

Вот код из файла functions.php:

```
<?php

function register_styles(){
    wp_register_style('pockets-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('pockets-bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('pockets-mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('pockets-mainstyle');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'register_styles');



function load_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri(). '/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', true);


    wp_enqueue_script('common', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/common.js', true);


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'load_scripts');






register_nav_menu ('menu', 'Main menu');
?>
```

К слову, если в подключении файла вместо wp_enqueue_script(...) прописываю wp_enqueue_scripts(...) мне браузер выдает Fatal error:Out of memory.

Помогите, плиз!

Answer (score 1):

У вас третий параметр 'wp_enqueue_script()' - true. А там должен быть массив зависимостей. Для jquery этот 3 параметр лучше убрать совсем. А для вашего скрипта 3 параметр должен выглядеть как 'array(' jquery')`.

Я бы так преобразовал ваш код:

```
<?php

function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pockets-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'pockets-mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );

function load_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js', array( 'query') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );

register_nav_menu( 'menu', 'Main menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так лучше

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    function register_styles() {        
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pockets-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css', array('pockets-bootstrap') );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );//отключаем js в wp
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', false, null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );//подключаем свой js

        wp_enqueue_script( 'commentjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js', array('jquery'));


    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_styles');


}
register_nav_menus(array(
    'menu'    => 'Верхнее меню',   
    'Main menu' => 'Мое меню'
```

Comment: Так-то оно лучше, но почему?))

Comment: Потому что это wp))

Comment: Вообще по моему лучше управлять своими скриптами, чем предложенными движком. Если ответ решен, ставь решен или есть еще вопросы?

Comment: Ща проверю твой код и отпишусь

Comment: Йоy, Алекс, cпасибо тебе огромное, все заработало теперь! А что, я неправильно грузил файлы? И зачем условие не админа?

Comment: @Александр это не ответ совсем. Написать-то вы написали правильный код, а почему он правильный - объяснить не можете)

Comment: @Mike_Gore в своём ответе я вам объяснил причину

Comment: Читай по wp  блоги. Я дал тебе лишь ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Mike_Gore а это бессмысленное условие. Типа, не подключать в админке. А они и так не подключатся в админке, потому что для скриптов и стилей в админке есть другой хук - admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Ой я тебя умоляю мало ли... Всё норм? И пусть так будет. А то еще что wp организация придумает

Comment: Что там не понятного? Подключается очередь стилей, потом отключается полностью jquery wp. Дальше подключаются свои js

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо большое за разъяснение !